Drizzle - Convert pg SelectedFields to plain type
I'm currently using Drizzle in a project and have implemented a repository pattern for the connection with Drizzle. The issue is that within the base class of the repositories, I have this method which has a 'select' property. This property is of type SelectedFields from pg.
export default class BaseRepository<TSchema extends PgTable, ID extends keyof TSchema["$inferSelect"]> {
  
  protected constructor(
    protected schema: TSchema,
    primaryKey: ID
  ) {
    this.primaryColumn = schema[primaryKey as keyof TSchema] as Column<ColumnBaseConfig<ColumnDataType, string>, object, object>;
  }

...

protected async findFirstBy<TSelection = InferSelectModel<TSchema>>({
    criteria,
    select,
    transaction
  }: FindFirstByParams<TSchema>): Promise<(TSelection extends SelectedFields ? TSelection : InferSelectModel<TSchema>) | null> {
    const connection = transaction || (await DrizzleSetup.getDrizzleInstance());

    try {
      let query;
      if (select) {
        query = connection.select(select).from(this.schema);
      } else {
        query = connection.select().from(this.schema);
      }

      const andQuery = this.parseCriteria(criteria);
      if (andQuery.length) query.where(and(...andQuery));

      const [result] = await query;

      return (result as TSelection extends SelectedFields ? TSelection : InferSelectModel<TSchema>) || null;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new DatabaseError("Error fetching record", { debugErrors: { error } });
    }
  }
...
}

And I have this typing:
import { SelectedFields, type PgTable } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export type FindFirstByParams<TSchema extends PgTable> = {
  criteria: QueryCriteria<TSchema>;
  select?: SelectedFields;
  transaction?: DrizzleTransaction;
}

Now, the problem is making the method return the correct typing, that is, not returning the complete schema but only what I'm selecting. Currently, my implementation of the method in the repository is this:
export class ProviderRepository extends BaseRepository<typeof providerSchema, "id"> {
  constructor() {
    super(providerSchema, "id");
  }

getProviderByName(paymentProviderName: string) {

    const select = {
      paymentProviderName: providerSchema.paymentProviderName,
      paymentProviderGateway: providerSchema.paymentGateway
    };

    return this.findFirstBy<typeof select>({
      criteria: {
        paymentProviderName
      },
      select
    });
  }
}

I have two possible cases, the first one is that it returns the whole schema and the typing works correctly this is only posible with out sending the select option.
Promise<{
    id: number;
    paymentProviderName: string;
    paymentGateway: string;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
} | null>

The second one returns the typing of the select object, that is:
Promise<{
    paymentProviderName: PgColumn<{
        name: "paymentProviderName";
        tableName: "provider";
        dataType: "string";
        columnType: "PgVarchar";
        data: string;
        driverParam: string;
        notNull: true;
        hasDefault: false;
        enumValues: [...];
        baseColumn: never;
    }, {}, {}>;
    paymentProviderGateway: PgColumn<...>;
} | null>

The issue arises when I try to use the returned object. Obviously, I encounter casting errors because when I try to send, for example, a string, a PgColumn type is sent instead, so the type that I need it's the first one but with the posibility of use select.
Any suggestion?
I've been reviewing the Drizzle code to see if there's an internal way to convert this select into a flat type, but I couldn't find anything.
